# whats wrong with my regex?

Tags: regex

I need to delete any character that's not 0 through 9, a through z, or A through Z.

heres my code:

```
$alt = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-fA-F]/', '', $_POST['alt-text']);
```

right now if i enter "alt text" in it turns it into "ae"

Comment: Why are you looking for A through F when your question says A through Z? That's probably related.

Comment: lol epic fail on my part.. I copied pasted it from somewhere else in my code and didn't change that lol thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a-f instead of a-z, same for A-Z.